# Confused on how to find a tangent

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $\operatorname{grad} f$ is tangent to the hyperbolas $xy = \mathrm{constant}$.  I'm confused on how to find the tangent.  I found the partial derivatives for $xy = c$,  $\dfrac{df}{dx} = y$ ; $\dfrac{df}{dy} = x$.  Grad f needs to be a multiple of the curve perpendicular to $xy = c$.  How do I find the tangent curve?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can find the tangent to $xy=c$ as

> $$ xy=c \implies xy'+y=0 \implies y'= - \frac{y}{x}. $$

Comment: I don't follow, how do you get that?